# Select an element based on one class when it has many

Tags: jquery, css

```
<span class="a b"/>
<span class="a b"/>
<span class="a b c"/>
```

How do I select the third element based on it being the only one with class c from a set containing all three spans?

```
var mySet = $("span");
var last = mySet.find(".c")
```

...doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, this is because `.find` looks for a child element of `span` in this case.

Comment: in jquery there is a function called `filter()` thats what you want

Comment: That's the answer!

Comment: I don't see a need for using filter() when you can select it just with the class `c` or a combination of classes that include `c`

Comment: what @j08691said... just do `$(".c")` adding the filter is more work for the browser to do... just get the one element you want. See my answer.

Comment: @j08691 Soz, jo, have added more detail to the question.

Comment: Have you read the jQuery DOCS what is actually the `.find()` method?

Comment: `.find()` searches descendant elements which isn't the case here

Answer (score 2):

Just use the class name you want to target. You don't need `span` too , that's overly specific, and unnecessary.

```
$(".c");

.c{

}
```

// ---- EDIT ---
You're question edit, makes it more clear, yet if your logic is that close I still think just targeting the one element you want is the best approach.
If you need the list of spans to use more than once you will want to use the `.filter()` method from the jQuery Object.

```
const $spans = $("span");
const $cSpan = $spans.filter(".c");
```

Note the $ on the variable names. This implies it's a jQuery object, not an element from the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You'd select it with:

```
span.a.b.c
```

```js
$('span.a.b.c').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

or

```
span.c
```

```js
$('span.c').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

or

```
span.b.c
```

```js
$('span.b.c').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

or

```
span.a.c
```

```js
$('span.a.c').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `using find`?

Comment: oh, find searches descendents.

Comment: I was using find instead of filter. I updated the question.

Comment: `<span/></span>`?

Comment: You forgot to add `$(".c")`  - and being *" third element"* examples :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks, fixed. And I left out `$(".c")` intentionally. While valid, I wanted to focus on the spans that he OP posted.